# conflicts when storing PublicKey as byte[] array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, byte

this is the first time im dealing with private and public keys and i was trying to store ECDSA PublicKey in MySQL DB and retrieve it later for use. Storing PublicKey to the DB is pretty easy but i was not able to convert it back to PublicKey after reading. After a simple google search i got some solution which recommended to store the PublicKey as byte array.
So, if the ECDSA PublicKey is 256bits long and after calling getEncoded() on the key it becomes something like "[B@3234e239", which clearly is 8 hexadecimal digits long. The length of the encoded key is now 8*4=32 bits long. If that's the case, why should we store the PublicKey as byte arrays when there is a huge chance of collision?

When i run the program, i get a new publickey on every run. However, the encoded version of the key is always the same.

[code output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79C5p.png), [output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdUC7.png), [code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax86O.png)

Comment: What do you mean by collision? You realize that it is still holds the same value, just in the different notation right?

Comment: Please refer to the edit, ive added some pics

Comment: You probably are confusing the encoded byte[] with its string representation. E.g. [B@3234... is NOT the encoded key it is the result of calling « toString() » on it. This is not the same.

Comment: You are not displaying the value. [B@3234e239 is the hashcode value of the object. To get the value you intended you need to override toString() method.

Comment: But i havent called the toString() method on the encoded key. Even the exact thing -[B@3234.. is stored in the database @GPI

Comment: `obj.toString()` is invoked automatically when using `print(obj)`. It defaults to the hashcode of that object.

Comment: What should i do if i want to store the exact encoded key to the DB

Comment: @Deo how can you tell the key is  [B@3234e239 in the DB? If you are getting it from the DB in your program and displaying it wint print() you are still going to invoke toString() method. Override toString() in your PublicKey class to display the actual key rather than object's hashcode. If you're using modern IDE it can do it for you automatically.

Comment: @MaciejMościcki i managed to get the actual encoded key using:
PublicKey public_key = CryptographyHelper.ellipticCurveCrypto().getPublic();
byte[] byte_pubkey = public_key.getEncoded();
String str_key = Arrays.toString(byte_pubkey);
printing str_key prints someting like [48, 70, 48, 16, 6, 7, 42,......

If im not wrong, this is the value that im going to store in the database?

Comment: btw im using netbeans 8.2